# Oracle startup and shutdown with Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I'm trying to automate the startup and shutdown of some Oracle instances with powershell.

The best I've come up with so far is below

```
param(
[String]$Instance = $(Throw 'Instance required' ),
[String]$Password = $(Throw 'Password required'),
[String]$ShutdownMode = 'IMMEDIATE'
)

$validShutdownModes = ('IMMEDIATE', 'NORMAL', 'ABORT')

if($validShutdownModes -notcontains $ShutdownMode)
{
    Throw 'Invalid ShutdownMode: [IMMEDIATE | NORMAL | ABORT]'
}

#Prepare the connection statement based on the Password and Instance name
$sqlConnect = 'connect sys/{0}@{1} as sysdba;' -f ($Password, $Instance)

#Prepare the shutdown statement based on the ShutdownMode
$sqlShutdown = 'shutdown {0};' -f ($ShutdownMode)

#Prepare the exit statement
$sqlExit = 'exit;'

#Get a temporary file for storing the SQLPLUS commands
$tmpFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

#Write the commands to the file
Set-Content -path $tmpFile -value $sqlConnect
Add-Content -path $tmpFile -value $sqlShutdown
Add-Content -path $tmpFile -value $sqlExit

#Execute the commands
$output = &'sqlplus.exe' '/NOLOG' '@' $tmpFile

#Remove the temporary file
Remove-Item -path $tmpFile

#Dump the ouput of SQLPLUS to the console
$output
```

This works, but its not able to deal with anything unexpected happening and writing passwords into temporary files is far from ideal.

Is there any programmatic interface I can use to shutdown Oracle instances, or a better way of using SQLPLUS for this kind of task?

Any general criticisms of the powershell in general are also appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with PowerShell.

However, how about using ORADIM, the Oracle built-in Windows-specific command-line to start/stop databases? It can stop/start database instances and ASM instance.

Using it is much cleaner than your workaround :)

See Oracle Documentation for it [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/create.htm#i1006533). It has startup and shutdown examples.

Answer (score 0):

Or use PowerShell to stop/start the OracleServiceSID.